# Failed to create symbolic link on WSL

Tags: sh, symlink, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ln

I want to create symbolic link using a script shared by my team. The script works fine on Mac, but this line:

```
ln -s `pwd`/git-hooks/post-checkout .git/hooks
```

failed on my Windows machine, WSL complains that:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘.git/hooks/post-checkout’: Input/output error
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The windows-version symbolic link already exists. WSL regards that as a normal file so it fails to create link there.

When I understand this I deleted those links and call the command again, the problem is solved.